# Create LINQ to entities OrderBy expression on the fly

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to add the orderby expression on the fly. But when the query below is executed I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable
>   to create a constant value of type
>   'Closure type'. Only primitive types
>   ('such as Int32, String, and Guid')
>   are supported in this context.

The strange thing is, I am query exactly those primitive types only.

```
string sortBy = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["sidx"];
ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(buskerPosting), "posting");
Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(prm, sortBy);

// get the paged records
IQueryable<PostingListItemDto> query =
   (from posting in be.buskerPosting
    where posting.buskerAccount.cmsMember.nodeId == m.Id
    orderby orderByProperty
    //orderby posting.Created 
    select new PostingListItemDto { Set = posting }).Skip<PostingListItemDto>((page -   1) * pageSize).Take<PostingListItemDto>(pageSize);
```

Hope somebody can shed some light on this!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You basically can't use query expressions like this, due to the way they're translated. However, you *can* do it explicitly with extension methods:

```
string sortBy = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["sidx"];
ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(buskerPosting), "posting");
Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(prm, sortBy);

// get the paged records
IQueryable<PostingListItemDto> query = be.buskerPosting
    .Where(posting => posting.buskerAccount.cmsMember.nodeId == m.Id)
    .OrderBy(orderByExpression)
    .Select(posting => new PostingListItemDto { Set = posting })
    .Skip<PostingListItemDto>((page -   1) * pageSize)
    .Take<PostingListItemDto>(pageSize);
```

The tricky bit is getting the right expression tree type - that'll come in an edit :)

EDIT: The edit will be somewhat delayed for various reasons. Basically you may need to call a generic method using reflection, as `Queryable.OrderBy` needs a generic `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` and although it looks like you know the *source* type at compile-time, you may not know the key type. If you *do* know it'll always be ordering by (say) an int, you can use:

```
Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(prm, sortBy);
var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<buskerPosting, int>>
    (orderByProperty, new[] { prm });
```

EDIT: Okay, it looks like I had time after all. Here's a short example of calling `OrderBy` using reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] names = { "Jon", "Holly", "Tom", "Robin", "Will" };
        var query = names.AsQueryable();
        query = CallOrderBy(query, "Length");
        foreach (var name in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod =
        typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
            .Where(method => method.Name == "OrderBy")
            .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .Single();

    public static IQueryable<TSource> CallOrderBy<TSource>
        (IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "posting");
        Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, new[] { parameter });
        Console.WriteLine(lambda);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod
            (new[] { typeof(TSource), orderByProperty.Type });
        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});
        return (IQueryable<TSource>) ret;
    }
}
```

You could easily refactor `CallOrderBy` into an extension method (e.g. `OrderByProperty`) like this:

```
public static class ReflectionQueryable
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod =
        typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
            .Where(method => method.Name == "OrderBy")
            .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .Single();

    public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderByProperty<TSource>
        (this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "posting");
        Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, new[] { parameter });
        Console.WriteLine(lambda);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod
            (new[] { typeof(TSource), orderByProperty.Type });
        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});
        return (IQueryable<TSource>) ret;
    }    
}
```

Your original code then becomes:

```
string sortBy = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["sidx"];
// get the paged records
IQueryable<PostingListItemDto> query = be.buskerPosting
    .Where(posting => posting.buskerAccount.cmsMember.nodeId == m.Id)
    .OrderByProperty(sortBy)
    .Select(posting => new PostingListItemDto { Set = posting })
    .Skip<PostingListItemDto>((page -   1) * pageSize)
    .Take<PostingListItemDto>(pageSize);
```

(Apologies for the formatting involving horizontal scrollbars... I'll reformat later if anyone cares. Or you could do it for me if you have enough rep ;)

Comment: Doesn't `OrderBy` expect a lambda expression? For example:  `Expression.Lambda<Func<T,U>>(orderByProperty, prm)`

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it expects an `Expression<...>` - which is why I used `orderByExpression` rather than `orderByProperty`. I was hoping to fill in the rest of the code, but something's come up so I won't be able to complete it right now.

Comment: This is gold. And you can easily make a descending version with code like `MethodInfo genericMethod = listSortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(TSource), orderByProperty.Type }): OrderByDescendingMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] {typeof(TSource), orderByProperty.Type });` where `OrderByDescendingMethod` is basicaly the same as `OrderByMethod` but has `OrderByDescending` in the text. You then just add a parameter `ListSortDirection` and you are away.

Comment: @JonSkeet @onefootswill,  in my case, if column is not a `string` type, but any other type of columns, like `int`, `decimal` or `DateTime`, then `OrderByDescending` always doesn't work. I am using EntityFrameworkCore 3.1+.  how to fix that? tons of thanks!

Comment: @Dongdong: Given that you're replying to an answer that was posted over 12 years ago, I would suggest creating a new question what you've tried and *precisely* what happened (rather than just "doesn't work").

Comment: @JonSkeet OMG! I wasn't aware that the question is so old. Thanks a lot. I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872972/linq-orderbydescending-doesnt-work-for-non-string-column-types-on-the-fly

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to share my implementation using Jon's answer above as a starting point. In this case, rather than sorting by a string property name coming from the presentation layer (since the title of this question isn't specific about that), I am building out an Entity Framework data layer and want to allow its consumer to specify order by properties as lambda expressions. I.E. Rather than passing `"sidx"`, I wanted to be able to use `p => p.sidx`. I also wanted to be able to pass an unlimited number of order by properties and be able to specify ascending or descending order.

Well my method can accept such a lambda expression as type `Expression<Func<T, object>>`. That let's me call it the way I want but the problem is, Entity Framework can't translate the expression to SQL unless the second generic parameter is strongly typed. The OrderBy extension method requires two generic parameters: T - the type the property belongs to, and TKey - the type the property returns. So the first step was to modify Jon's example to convert a given `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to a `Expression<Func<T, Tkey>>` (once we're working within the context of a query, we can determine the type `TKey`):

```
internal static IQueryable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> sortExp)
{
    //We need to convert the key selector from Expression<Func<T, object>> to a strongly typed Expression<Func<T, TKey>>
    //in order for Entity Framework to be able to translate it to SQL
    MemberExpression orderByMemExp = ExpressionHelpers.RemoveConvert(sortExp.Body) as MemberExpression;
    ParameterExpression sourceParam = sortExp.Parameters[0];

    LambdaExpression orderByLamda = Expression.Lambda(orderByMemExp, new[] { sourceParam });

    MethodInfo orderByMethod = OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), orderByMemExp.Type });

    //Call OrderBy or OrderByDescending on the source IQueryable<T>
    return (IQueryable<T>)orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, orderByLamda });
}
```

As I mentioned, I want to accept an unlimited number of order by key selectors and also have the ability to specify the ascending or descending direction so I made a wrapper class for the `Expression<Func<T, object>>` which I named DynamicSortExpression:

```
public class DynamicSortExpression<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new ascending DynamicSortExpression 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A MemberExpression identifying the property to sort on</param>
    public DynamicSortExpression(Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector) : this(keySelector, false)
    {
    }

    public DynamicSortExpression(Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, bool descending)
    {
        this.KeySelector = keySelector;
        this.Desc = descending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the expression that selects the property of T to sort on
    /// </summary>
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> KeySelector { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets sort expression is in ascending or descending order
    /// </summary>
    public bool Desc { get; }
}
```

Then I updated the extension method to accept this type and created an overload for `OrderBy` that receives a `List<DynamicSortExpression<T>>` and adds them to the query using the extension method(s) one by one.  Here is the final result:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                        .Where(method => method.Name == "OrderBy")
                                                        .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                        .Single();

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByDescMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                            .Where(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending")
                                                            .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                            .Single();

    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                    .Where(method => method.Name == "ThenBy")
                                                    .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                    .Single();

    private static readonly MethodInfo ThenByDescMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                    .Where(method => method.Name == "ThenByDescending")
                                                    .Where(method => method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                    .Single();

    internal static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> sourceQuery, List<DynamicSortExpression<T>> orderBy)
    {
        bool isFirst = true;
        foreach (var sortExpression in orderBy)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                sourceQuery = sourceQuery.OrderByDynamic(sortExpression);
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
                sourceQuery = sourceQuery.ThenByDynamic(sortExpression);
        }

        return sourceQuery;
    }

    internal static IQueryable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, DynamicSortExpression<T> sortExpression)
    {
        //We need to convert the key selector from Expression<Func<T, object>> to a strongly typed Expression<Func<T, TKey>>
        //in order for Entity Framework to be able to translate it to SQL
        MemberExpression orderByMemExp = ExpressionHelpers.RemoveConvert(sortExpression.KeySelector.Body) as MemberExpression;
        ParameterExpression sourceParam = sortExpression.KeySelector.Parameters[0];

        LambdaExpression orderByLamda = Expression.Lambda(orderByMemExp, new[] { sourceParam });

        MethodInfo orderByMethod = sortExpression.Desc ?
                                        OrderByDescMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), orderByMemExp.Type }) :
                                        OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), orderByMemExp.Type });

        //Call OrderBy or OrderByDescending on the source IQueryable<T>
        return (IQueryable<T>)orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, orderByLamda });
    }

    internal static IQueryable<T> ThenByDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, DynamicSortExpression<T> sortExpression)
    {
        //We need to convert the key selector from Expression<Func<T, object>> to a strongly typed Expression<Func<T, TKey>>
        //in order for Entity Framework to be able to translate it to SQL
        Expression orderByMemExp = ExpressionHelpers.RemoveConvert(sortExpression.KeySelector.Body) as MemberExpression;
        ParameterExpression sourceParam = sortExpression.KeySelector.Parameters[0];

        LambdaExpression orderByLamda = Expression.Lambda(orderByMemExp, new[] { sourceParam });

        MethodInfo orderByMethod = sortExpression.Desc ?
                                        ThenByDescMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), orderByMemExp.Type }) :
                                        ThenByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T), orderByMemExp.Type });

        //Call OrderBy or OrderByDescending on the source IQueryable<T>
        return (IQueryable<T>)orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, orderByLamda });
    }
}
```

Now my data layer can have a method like `List<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params DynamicSortExpression<T>[] orderBy)` that can be called like

```
new MyClass<Person>().GetList(p => p.FirstName == "Billy", //where clause
                              new DynamicSortExpression<Person>(p => p.FirstName),
                              new DynamicSortExpression<Person>(p => p.LastName, true));
```

Where internally, `MyClass<T>.GetList` builds the query which calls my `OrderBy` extension method. Something like:

```
DBContext.Set<T>().Where(whereParam).OrderBy(orderByParams);
```

The `RemoveConvert` method is something I yanked out of the EntityFramework source code to recursively remove Convert calls from a MemberExpression:

```
internal static Expression RemoveConvert(Expression expression)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(expression != null);

    while ((expression != null)
            && (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
                || expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked))
    {
        expression = RemoveConvert(((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand);
    }

    return expression;
}
```

I hope this is helpful! Thanks Jon!