# How to construct Order By Expression dynamically in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used the following methods to construct **Order By Expression**. [Original Source](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-43e5de16/sourcecode?fileId=139277&pathId=481390404)

It is really slick. The downside is it only works if Property is **string** type.

How can I make it to accept different Property type *without creating a bunch of methods for different data types*?

```
public static bool PropertyExists<T>(string propertyName)
{
    return typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |
      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null;
}

public static Expression<Func<T, string>> GetPropertyExpression<T>(string propertyName)
{
    if (typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    return (Expression<Func<T, string>>)Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(paramterExpression, propertyName), paramterExpression);
}
```

### Usage

```
// orderBy can be either Name or City.
if (QueryHelper.PropertyExists<Club>(orderBy)) 
{ 
   var orderByExpression = QueryHelper.GetPropertyExpression<Club>(orderBy); 
   clubQuery = clubQuery.OrderBy(orderByExpression); 
} 
else 
{ 
   clubQuery = clubQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Id); 
}
```

### Problem

```
public class Club 
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string City { get; set; } 
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } <= this won't work
}
```

### My Current Approach *(Too many if statements)*

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> 
    GetPropertyExpression<TSource, TKey>(string propertyName)
{
    if (typeof (TSource).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TSource));
    return (Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>) 
        Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(
           paramterExpression, propertyName), paramterExpression);
}
```

The downside is I end up with a lot of if statements for each datatype.

```
if (QueryHelper.PropertyExists<Club>(orderBy)) 
{
   if(orderBy == "CreateDate")
   {       
      var orderByExpression = GetPropertyExpression<Club, DateTime>(orderBy);
      ...
   }
   else if(orderBy == "Name" || orderBy == "City")
   {
      var orderByExpression = GetPropertyExpression<Club, string>(orderBy);
      ...
   }
   ...
}
else 
{ 
   clubQuery = clubQuery.OrderBy(c => c.Id); 
}
```

Comment: So it is at the `var orderByExpression = QueryHelper.GetPropertyExpression<Club>(orderBy);` that it causes the problem?

Comment: The problem is too many repeated code for each data type. Please kindly refer to the last code I posted. It seems that very common problem for whoever use dynamic **OrderBy**; but I could not find any solution in Google. ***I'm open to any suggestion or alternative approach***.

Comment: Rather than passing in "CreateDate" or "Name" or "City" or what not, I'd pass in some sort of object that represents the property to sort by.  This object would have the ability to generate a sort expression, and other useful things.  More code, but no messy *if* jungle.

Comment: @MikeChristensen what would be the type of the returned `Expression`?

Comment: @moarboilerplate - Hmm, I suppose `LambdaExpression`?  The only thing `Expression<TDelegate>` gives you is `Compile` and `Update` which he probably doesn't need.

Comment: @MikeChristensen the difficulty is actually with `TDelegate`. In order to return a delegate that can handle different types, the delegate signature has to use an intrinsically generic type like `object`, and then after you get your object, you have to figure out how to cast it.

Comment: Yea, I'm saying the implementations for each field type would do that..  There should be a `CreateDateField` class, and `CityField` class, etc.  Each would implement an interface, which has a `GenerateSortExpression` that returns `LambaExpression`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2841605/296861)'s old answer.

```
public static class QueryHelper
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod =
        typeof (Queryable).GetMethods().Single(method => 
        method.Name == "OrderBy" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByDescendingMethod =
        typeof (Queryable).GetMethods().Single(method => 
        method.Name == "OrderByDescending" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    public static bool PropertyExists<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) != null;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByProperty<T>(
       this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        if (typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        ParameterExpression paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
        Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(paramterExpression, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, paramterExpression);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = 
          OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (T), orderByProperty.Type);
        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});
        return (IQueryable<T>) ret;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyDescending<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
    {
        if (typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        ParameterExpression paramterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
        Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(paramterExpression, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(orderByProperty, paramterExpression);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = 
          OrderByDescendingMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (T), orderByProperty.Type);
        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});
        return (IQueryable<T>) ret;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
string orderBy = "Name";
if (query.PropertyExists(orderBy))
{
   query = query.OrderByProperty(orderBy);
   - OR - 
   query = query.OrderByPropertyDescending(orderBy);
}
```

Comment: Did we really expect anyone else to have an answer? ;)

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to also sort on Navigation properties of current entity ?

Comment: Excellent solution! My only question is how can I order by an subordinate object? For instance, if I have an object `Apple { Kernel { Size = 13 } }` how would I order the query on the `Size` property? Setting `orderBy` in the example to `"Kernel.Size"` doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work with EF Core 3.1. Any suggestions on how to make it work right?

Comment: there should be a way to take an sql expression on the order by and evaluate the fields and operators then generate the c# code, a code generator.   This seems like a verbose way to dynamically add an order by.

Answer (score 6):

option 1 :
this can done using expression : check this [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5PlilF)

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyOrField<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string propertyOrFieldName, bool ascending = true)
{
        var elementType = typeof (T);
        var orderByMethodName = ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(elementType);
        var propertyOrFieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, propertyOrFieldName);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(propertyOrFieldExpression, parameterExpression);

        var orderByExpression = Expression.Call(typeof (Queryable), orderByMethodName,
                                                new[] {elementType, propertyOrFieldExpression.Type}, queryable.Expression, selector);

        return queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByExpression);
}
```

option 2 (if you are using ef core):

```
 public static IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyOrderBy<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string? orderBy, string orderDirection)
{
        if (orderBy is null) return query;
        
        query = orderDirection == "Asc"
            ? query.OrderBy(p => EF.Property<TEntity>(p!, orderBy))
            : query.OrderByDescending(p => EF.Property<TEntity>(p!, orderBy));

        return query;
 }
```

Comment: The EFCore solution is without equal. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

**I have, IMHO, a simpler solution:**

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Sort<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool ascending , string sortingProperty)
{
    if (ascending)
        return source.OrderBy(item => item.GetReflectedPropertyValue(sortingProperty));
    else
        return source.OrderByDescending(item => item.GetReflectedPropertyValue(sortingProperty));
}

private static object GetReflectedPropertyValue(this object subject, string field)
{
    return subject.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(subject, null);
}
```

**The usage is:**

```
myQueryableCollection.Sort(ascending: true, "Name")
```

Of course, the `PropertyExist()` helper is a great addition...

Comment: Hi, does this work in EF Core 3? It throws for me:

.OrderByDescending(e0 => (object)e0
        .GetReflectedPropertyValue(__filter_Sort_Predicate_3))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToLi
st(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Doesn't work: `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ImportLog>
    .Where(i => .....)
    .OrderBy(i => (object)i
        .GetReflectedPropertyValue(__sortingProperty_0))' could not be translated. `

Comment: @Ian if it doesn't translate is because you are sending the query directly to the database. You have to get the results with a ToList() or similar before.