# How to fix 'No property or field exists in type' error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I got this error when trying to sort any columns that are not in the Order table, if I use `OrderBy("Customer.CompanyName" + " " + sortDir)` the error will gone but all the columns will become unable to sort. The `OrderBy` method used below come from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/UI/WebControls/Dynamic.cs).

What is the cause of the problem ?

```cs
    public ActionResult WebGrid(int page = 1, int rowsPerPage = 10, string sortCol = "OrderID", string sortDir = "ASC")
    {
        List<Order> res;
        using (var nwd = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
             var _res = nwd.Orders
                .OrderBy(sortCol + " " + sortDir)
                .Select(o => new Order
                {
                    OrderID = o.OrderID,
                    OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                    CompanyName = o.Customer.CompanyName,
                    FirstName = o.Employee.FirstName,
                    //......
                    //......
                    //......
                });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class you provided the link to is marked as `internal` and it can't be used outside the assembly it was defined in, so you can't use it in your code.

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code. Provides functionality to create new
>   classes from values in a LinqDataSource control.

So What you're actually trying to use is [OrderBy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,326) inside `Queryable` class which is part of `System.Linq` which can be used as following:

```
.OrderBy(x=> x.sortCol + " " + x.sortDir)
```

If you're trying to order by two columns, then you can use:

```
.OrderBy(x=> x.sortCol).ThenBy(x=> x.sortDir)
```

If you want to dynamically specify the OrderBy expression, you can either do a switch statement for each possible parameter, or follow this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34908081/3185569) to build a dynamic Expression Tree.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I cannot use `ThenBy` under dynamic linq.

Comment: Thanks for help! I found that I can use else if statement to achieve this.

Comment: He's actually using dynamic Linq/OrderBy. You're answer assumes there is no way of using it while there is. The ThenBy in dynamicLinq should be used like this : "ColumnName ASC, ColumnName2 DESC, ColumnName3 ASC". He's problem occurs because he's trying to sort on a column that's not part of the target object. That's also what i'm trying to acheive, the dynamic way. If you have any solution, please update your answer !

Comment: Check `sortCol`. It may be empty and that will cause the error `field asc not exist`