# entity framework core 3 dynamic order by not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public class Branch
 {
    [Sortable(OrderBy = "BranchId")]
    public long BranchId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Model class and I also create a custom attribute

```
public class SortableAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string OrderBy { get; set; }
    }
```

now i create a pagination with orderby descending but this code not working

```
public static async Task<IPagedList<T>> ToPagedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
            GeneralPagingRequest pagingRequest, int indexFrom = 0,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (indexFrom > pagingRequest.PageNumber)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"indexFrom: {indexFrom} > pageNumber: {pagingRequest.PageNumber}, must indexFrom <= pageNumber");
            }

            var count = await source.CountAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var items = source.Skip(((pagingRequest.PageNumber - 1) - indexFrom) * pagingRequest.PageSize)
                .Take(pagingRequest.PageSize);
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo orderByProperty;
            orderByProperty =
                    props.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortableAttribute), true).Length != 0);


            if (pagingRequest.OrderBy == "desc")
            {
                items = items.OrderBy(x => orderByProperty.GetValue(x));
            }
            else
            {
                items = items.OrderBy(x => orderByProperty.GetValue(x));
            }

            var result = await items.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var pagedList = new PagedList<T>
            {
                PageNumber = pagingRequest.PageNumber,
                PageSize = pagingRequest.PageSize,
                IndexFrom = indexFrom,
                TotalCount = count,
                Items = result,
                TotalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling(count / (double) pagingRequest.PageSize)
            };

            return pagedList;
}
```

but the result variable create exception

Answer (score 0):

[`.OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_OrderBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) requires a delegate that would tell it **HOW** to select a key, not the key value itself. So you are looking at some meta-programming here.

Naturally, you will look at building a dynamic LINQ Expression tree that will fetch a property for you:

```
// your code up above
PropertyInfo orderByProperty = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortableAttribute), true).Length != 0);

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"); // you define your delegate parameter here
var accessor = Expression.Property(p, orderByProperty.GetMethod); // this basically becomes your `x => x.BranchId` construct
var predicate = Expression.Lambda(accessor, p).Compile(); // here's our problem: as we don't know resulting type at compile time we can't go `Expression.Lambda<T, long>(accessor, p)` here

if (pagingRequest.OrderBy == "desc")
{
    items = items.OrderByDescending(x => predicate(x)); // passing a Delegate here will not work as OrderBy requires Func<T, TKey>
}
else
{
    items = items.OrderBy(x => predicate(x)); // passing a Delegate here will not work as OrderBy requires Func<T, TKey>
}

var result = await items.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
// your code down below
```

Problem with the above code - you don't know `TKey` upfront. Therefore we will have to go a level deeper and build the whole `items.OrderBy(x => x.BranchId)` expression dynamically. The biggest leap of faith here will be the fact the `OrderBy` is an extension method and it actually resides on `IQueryable` type. After you've got the generic method reference, you will need to build a specific delegate type when you know your property type. So your method becomes something like this:

```
public static class ExtToPagedListAsync
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "OrderBy" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2); // you need your method reference, might as well find it once

    private static readonly MethodInfo OrderByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "OrderByDescending" && method.GetParameters().Length == 2); // you need your method reference, might as well find it once

    public static async Task<IPagedList<T>> ToPagedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, GeneralPagingRequest pagingRequest, int indexFrom = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        if (indexFrom > pagingRequest.PageNumber)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"indexFrom: {indexFrom} > pageNumber: {pagingRequest.PageNumber}, must indexFrom <= pageNumber");
        }

        var count = await source.CountAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var items = source.Skip(((pagingRequest.PageNumber - 1) - indexFrom) * pagingRequest.PageSize)
            .Take(pagingRequest.PageSize);
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo orderByProperty = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortableAttribute), true).Length != 0);

        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var accessor = Expression.Property(p, orderByProperty.GetMethod);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda(accessor, p); // notice, we're not yet compiling the predicate. we still want an Expression here

        // grab the correct method depending on your condition
        MethodInfo genericMethod = (pagingRequest.OrderBy == "desc") ? OrderByDescendingMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), orderByProperty.PropertyType)
                                                                    :OrderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), orderByProperty.PropertyType);

        object ret = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { items, predicate });
        items = (IQueryable<T>)ret; // finally cast it back to Queryable with your known T

        var result = await items.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var pagedList = new PagedList<T>
        {
            PageNumber = pagingRequest.PageNumber,
            PageSize = pagingRequest.PageSize,

            IndexFrom = indexFrom,
            TotalCount = count,
            Items = result,
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pagingRequest.PageSize)
        };

        return pagedList;
    }
}
```

I must disclose I did get some inspiration from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906437/how-to-construct-order-by-expression-dynamically-in-entity-framework), so do check it out for further reading.