# Return Expression from a method to be used in OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I want to write an abstract method to be overridden by child classes, and what the method does is return an expression to be subsequently used in LINQ `OrderBy()`. Something like this:

Note: `Message` inherits from `Notes` class, and `MyModel` inherits from `MsgModel`.

```
public class Notes
{
    // abstract definition; using object so that I can (I hope) order by int, string, etc.
    public abstract Expression<Func<MsgModel, object>> OrderByField();
    // ...

    private string GetOrderByFieldName()
    {
        // I am not sure how to write this
        // This is my problem 2. Please see below for problem 1 :-(

        var lambda = OrderByField() as LambdaExpression;

        MemberExpression member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;

        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        return propInfo.Name;
    }
}

public class Message : Notes
{
    // second type parameter is object because I don't know the type
    // of the orderby field beforehand
    public override Expression<Func<MyModel, object>> OrderByField()
    {
        return m => m.item_no;
    }
}
```

Now if I try to order by this way:

```
var orderedQuery = myQueryable.OrderBy(OrderByField());
```

I get this error:

> 'Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'

I can rightaway say that type parameter object is the cause of the problem. So, when I change the type parameter to int, it works fine as long as I am ordering by an int field (e.g. the field `item_no`).

Q1. How can I get this to work? Surely, I can use a string property `OrderByField` instead of that expression-returning method and order by it, probably by writing some extension method for IQueryable (maybe using [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841585/create-linq-to-entities-orderby-expression-on-the-fly)). But I want to have more intellisense while setting the order by.

Q2. How can I get the name of the order by column from the expression returned by the method `OrderByField()`. Obviously what I have tried with doesn't work. The `member` always gets null.

---

**Edit:** I have made some changes to the type parameters of the methods. Sorry for not doing it the first time.

Comment: Can you not make `Notes` generic in the data type it will return from that expression?

Comment: @Damien I am not sure I understood properly what you meant :-( Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: If you are meaning this `Expression<Func<MsgModel, T>> OrderByField<T>()`, then I get this error: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: Well, you can *define* it that way (`Expression<Func<Notes, object>>`), but you can't *use* it directly in `OrderBy`. And if you need intellisense for `OrderBy`, then why not using `OrderBy` itself?

Comment: My situation is that the child classes will implement `OrderByField()` (note that `Notes` is an abstract class). The class `MyModel` has the order by field, and only `Message` class knows which field to order by. And, the base class `Notes` uses the order by field set by its child to do some other stuff. Does that make sense?

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile (the `Notes` class is not abstract, there is a change in the `OrderByField` signature between the two classes). Can you fix it and provide us the definition of MsgModel and MyModel (at least the type of `item_no`)?

Comment: My point was that it shouldn't be modelled as abstract `Expression<Func<...>>`, but abstract `Order` method, for instance `public abstract IOrderedQueryable<MsgModel> Order(IQueryable<MsgModel> source);` with implementations like `return source.OrderBy(m => m.item_no);`

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I know that I could solve my problem with what you've shown. In fact my current code is written that way, but I wanted to change that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the `Expression<Func<T, object>>` is not equivalent of `Expression<Func<T, K>>`, hence cannot be used as direct replacement of the later required by `Queryable.OrderBy<T, K>` and similar methods.

Still it's possible to make it work with the help of `Expression` class by creating a non generic `LambdaExpression` via [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052(v=vs.110).aspx) method and dynamically emitting a call to the corresponding `Queryable` method.

Here is all that encapsulated in a custom extension methods (a modified version of my answer to [How to use a string to create a EF order by expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908403/how-to-use-a-string-to-create-a-ef-order-by-expression/39916384#39916384)):

```
public static partial class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, "OrderBy");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, "OrderByDescending");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, "ThenBy");
    }
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, "ThenByDescending");
    }
    private static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, string method)
    {
        var parameter = keySelector.Parameters[0];
        var body = keySelector.Body;
        if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
        var methodCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), method, new[] { parameter.Type, body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(methodCall);
    }
}
```

One important detail here is that `Expression<Func<T, object>>` introduces [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) for value type returning expressions, so it needs to be stripped from the actual lambda *body*, which is accomplished with the following part of the code:

```
var body = keySelector.Body;
if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
    body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a couple of generic types for your `Notes` class. The first is so you can derive from it and still allow the expression to filter on the derived class. The second is to specify the type of the property you wish to use to order by. For example:

```
public abstract class Notes<T, TProperty> where T : Notes<T, TProperty>
{
    public abstract Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> OrderByField();

    public string GetOrderByFieldName()
    {
        //snip
    }
}

public class Message : Notes<Message, int>
{
    public int item_no { get; set; }

    public override Expression<Func<Message, int>> OrderByField()
    {
        return m => m.item_no;
    }
}
```

This should also allow the `GetOrderByFieldName` method to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my project structure doesn't allow me to create _a number of generic types_ for `Notes` class, so much so that if your solution is indeed the only solution, then I may need to look for workarounds for `GetOrderByFieldName` method implementation.

Comment: Without a generic type, your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Then I guess I am going to have look for some plan B for `GetOrderByFieldName`.

Comment: It's not just that, but you can't override in the `Message` class with a different type for `OrderByField`.

Comment: Before I saw your answer, I was thinking if there is a way to define a _pack_ of abstract OrderBy methods in the base class with different type parameters, but a child class would be required to override just one of the pack, depending on the type of the order by field it is going to use, which is obviously impossible, and I know I sound stupid! The idea of generic base class didn't hit me, until I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does (almost) not use reflection or expression stuff:
It exploits the fact that the ordering LINQ functions have just one generic type in their result.

1st, create an interface (only one generic parameter) and an implementation (with two generic parameters):

```
public interface ISortCrit<TSource>
{
    string SortFieldName { get; }

    IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeOrderBy(IEnumerable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeOrderByDescending(IEnumerable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeThenBy(IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeThenByDescending(IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source);

    IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeOrderBy(IQueryable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeOrderByDescending(IQueryable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeThenBy(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source);
    IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeThenByDescending(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source);
}

public class SortCrit<TSource, TSort> : ISortCrit<TSource>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<TSource, TSort>> _sortExpression;
    private readonly Lazy<Func<TSource, TSort>> _sortDelegate;
    private readonly Lazy<string> _sortFieldName;

    public SortCrit(Expression<Func<TSource, TSort>> sortExpression)
    {
        _sortExpression = sortExpression;
        _sortDelegate = new Lazy<Func<TSource, TSort>>(() => sortExpression.Compile());
        _sortFieldName = new Lazy<string>(() => ((MemberExpression)sortExpression.Body).Member.Name);
    }

    public string SortFieldName => _sortFieldName.Value;

    public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeOrderBy(IEnumerable<TSource> source) => source.OrderBy(_sortDelegate.Value);
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeOrderByDescending(IEnumerable<TSource> source) => source.OrderByDescending(_sortDelegate.Value);
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeThenBy(IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source) => source.ThenBy(_sortDelegate.Value);
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> MakeThenByDescending(IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source) => source.ThenBy(_sortDelegate.Value);

    public IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeOrderBy(IQueryable<TSource> source) => source.OrderBy(_sortExpression);
    public IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeOrderByDescending(IQueryable<TSource> source) => source.OrderByDescending(_sortExpression);
    public IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeThenBy(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source) => source.ThenBy(_sortExpression);
    public IOrderedQueryable<TSource> MakeThenByDescending(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source) => source.ThenByDescending(_sortExpression);
}
```

2nd some conveniance extensions:

```
public static class SortCrit
{
    public static ISortCrit<TSource> Create<TSource, TSort>(Expression<Func<TSource, TSort>> sortExpression) => new SortCrit<TSource, TSort>(sortExpression);

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeOrderBy(source);
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeOrderByDescending(source);
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource>(this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeThenBy(source);
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenByDescending<TSource>(this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeThenByDescending(source);

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeOrderBy(source);
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescending<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeOrderByDescending(source);
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeThenBy(source);
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenByDescending<TSource>(this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, ISortCrit<TSource> crit) => crit.MakeThenByDescending(source);
}
```

Usage:

```
var messageCrit = SortCrit.Create((Message m) => m.ItemNo);

IEnumerable<Message> msgs = ...;
msgs.OrderBy(messageCrit);
```